# obtaining error number of an error

Tags: python, error-handling, paramiko

I need to obtain the error number from an error that has occurred in Python.

Ex; When trying to transfer a directory via the Paramiko package, an error is caught with this piece of code:

```
try:
    sftp.put(local_path,target_path)    
except (IOError,OSError),errno:
    print "Error:",errno
```

For which I get the output,

```
Error: [Errno 21] Is a directory
```

I want to utilize the error number to go into some more code to transfer the directory and the directory contents.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question.

Most `Exception`s in Python don't have "error numbers". One exception (no pun intended) are `HTTPError` exceptions, for example:

```
import urllib2 
try:
   page = urllib2.urlopen("some url")
except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
   if err.code == 404:
       print "Page not found!"
   else:
       ...
```

Another exception (as noted by bobince) are `EnvironmentError`s:

```
import os
try:
   f=open("hello")
except IOError, err:
   print err
   print err.errno
   print err.strerror
   print err.filename
```

outputs

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hello'
2
No such file or directory
hello
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Note for OSError, it looks like these are **all None** (including errno) unless at least two args are specified to the exception, with filename being the optional third argument.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about `errno.h` error numbers, you can get them from the `errno` property on the exception object, but only on `EnvironmentError` (which includes `OSError`, `IOError` and `WindowsError`).

Specifically on `WindowsError` you'll also get a `winerror` property with a Windows-specific error number. (You don't often see one of these though, as Python uses the Win32 API directly relatively rarely.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno) package, which allows working with error codes with out having to handle magic numbers in the code. See an example here: [Are Python error numbers associated with IOError stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283377/are-python-error-numbers-associated-with-ioerror-stable)