# Are Python error numbers associated with IOError stable?

Tags: python, api, exception, error-handling, errno

I want to move a file, but in the case it is not found I should just ignore it. In all other cases the exception should be propagated. I have the following piece of Python code:

```
try:
    shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno != 2: raise e
```

errno == 2 is the one, that has 'No such file or directory' description. I wonder if this is stable across Python versions and platforms, and etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better to use values from the [errno](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#module-errno) module instead of hardcoding the value `2`:

```
try:
    shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: raise e
```

This makes your code less likely to break in case the integer error value changes (although that is unlikely to occur).

Comment: "unlikely" is an understatement - the number of programs that would break is mind boggling, it will *never* happen. But using a symbol rather than a magic number is always preferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not even know, such a module exists. This is exactly what I wanted.